# Collect, filter and display archive logs on demand

Tags: php, html, bash

Wrote a `php` site to gather/filter/search daily archived logs from the archive directory using bash `cat` and `grep` commands.

1. How can I make the code more readable?
2. How can I follow conventions better ? (functions/indentation/comments/ using php and html together etc)
3. Is there a different approach to this problem I should try?

**UI:**

---

[image: Cropped screenshot of the user interface]

---

**CODE:**

```
####### Get params for query : check both Post and Get ################
####### This part needs to go in to a function later #############

$isset=0; #used to check if at least one of the mandatory fields were checked - avoids returning the whole logfilefor fair players
$host = "";
if(isset($_POST['host'])){ #higher priority for post
    $host = $_POST['host'];
    $isset++;
}elseif(isset($_GET['host'])){ #check get only if post wasn't set
    $host = $_GET['host'];
    $isset++;
}
$service = "";
if(isset($_POST['service'])){
    $service = $_POST['service'];
    $isset++;
}elseif(isset($_GET['service'])){
    $service = $_GET['service'];
    $isset++;
}
$preserve = "";
if(isset($_POST['preserve'])){
    $preserve = $_POST['preserve'];
}
# start input of 8 checkbox buttons
$ok = "";
if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
    $ok = $_POST['ok'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['ok'])){
    $ok = $_GET['ok'];
}
$warn = "";
if(isset($_POST['warn'])){
    $warn = $_POST['warn'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['warn'])){
    $warn = $_GET['warn'];
}
$crit = "";
if(isset($_POST['crit'])){
    $crit = $_POST['crit'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['crit'])){
    $crit = $_GET['crit'];
}
$Curr = "";
if(isset($_POST['curr'])){
    $curr = $_POST['curr'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['curr'])){
    $curr = $_GET['curr'];
}
$alert = "";
if(isset($_POST['alert'])){
    $alert = $_POST['alert'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['alert'])){
    $alert = $_GET['alert'];
}
$notif = "";
if(isset($_POST['notif'])){
    $notif = $_POST['notif'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['notif'])){
    $notif = $_GET['notif'];
}
$comm = "";
if(isset($_POST['comm'])){
    $comm = $_POST['comm'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['comm'])){
    $comm = $_GET['comm'];
}
$soft = "";
if(isset($_POST['soft'])){
    $soft = $_POST['soft'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['soft'])){
    $soft = $_GET['soft'];
}
######### END ## "Get Params for check################
######################################################



?>
<HTML>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


            You are viewing logs for this whole month, more specific date options will be added later
            <form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                        <h2><span>
             Enter host or service:&nbsp&nbsp
            <br>Service: <input type="text" name="service" value="<?php echo $service; ?>" size=50>
                        <br>Host: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input type="text" name="host" value="<?php echo $host; ?>" size=50>
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="ok" value="ok"<?php if($preserve != "" && $ok != ""){echo " checked";}else{}  ?> >OK&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            <input type="checkbox" name="warn" value="warn" checked="checked">WARNING&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            <input type="checkbox" name="crit" value="crit" checked="checked">CRITICAL 
            <br><input type="checkbox" name="curr" value="curr" checked="checked">Current State* &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            <input type="checkbox" name="alert" value="alert" checked="checked">Alert&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            <input type="checkbox" name="notif" value="notif" >Notification (sms/mail) &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            <input type="checkbox" name="comm" value="comm" checked="command">Commands (dt/ack etc) &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            <input type="checkbox" name="soft" value="soft" checked="stop inspecting my elements" >Soft state<br> 
                <input type="hidden" name="preserve" value="preserve" >
            <input type="submit" value="Check"></span></h2>


<?php

##############################################################
############# Use params to set the grep filter ###############
$grepfilter="";
if($service != ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -e " . $service;
} 
if($host != ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -e " . $host;
} 
if($ok == ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -v \";OK;\"";
}
if($warn == ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -v \";WARNING;\"";
}
if($crit == ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -v \";CRITICAL;\"";
}
if($notif == ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -v \"SERVICE NOTIFICATION: \"";
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -v \"HOST NOTIFICATION: \"";
}
if($alert == ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -v \"SERVICE ALERT: \"";
}
if($curr == ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -v \"CURRENT SERVICE STATE: \"  | grep -v \"CURRENT HOST STATE: \"";
}
if($comm == ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -v \"EXTERNAL COMMAND: \" | grep -v \"SERVICE DOWNTIME ALERT: \" ";
}
if($soft == ""){
    $grepfilter .= " | grep -v \";SOFT;\"";
}

####################################################
#########  run bash code and parse ourput #########
if($isset>0){ 
    $output = shell_exec('cat /usr/local/groundwork/nagios/var/archives/nagios-08-**-2016-**.log' . $grepfilter); # bash core code for archived
    $output .= shell_exec('cat /usr/local/groundwork/nagios/var/nagios.log' . $grepfilter);   # same code on logs not yet archived 

    $output = str_replace("critical","<b><font color=\"red\">critical</font></b>",$output); #mark words with colors
    $output = str_replace("CRITICAL","<b><font color=\"red\">CRITICAL</font></b>",$output);
    $output = str_replace("warning","<b><font color=\"orange\">warning</font></b>",$output);
    $output = str_replace("WARNING","<b><font color=\"orange\">WARNING</font></b>",$output);
    $output = str_replace("NOT OK","<b><font color=\"red\">NOT 0K</font></b>",$output);
    $output = str_replace("OK","<b><font color=\"green\">OK</font></b>",$output);
    $output = preg_replace_callback("/(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)/",function ($matches) {  # switch epoch time to date time
                return date("Y-m-d | H:i:s",$matches[0]);},$output);
    $arr = explode("\n",$output);  #split lines to array
    $arr = array_reverse($arr);    #reverse array to get order newest to olders
    $output = implode("\n",$arr);  # join array back to string
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}else{
     echo "please select at least one of the host/service fields"
;}

 ?>
<br>
</body>
<HTML>
```

**OUTPUT EXAMPLE:**
[image: Obfuscated logging lines]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Security: XSS**

You are vulnerable to persistent XSS attacks via the logs, which may or may not currently be a problem, depending on whether or not the log input is user-supplied. I definitely wouldn't trust that they never contain user input, so you should definitely defend against this.

You are also vulnerable to reflected XSS via `service` and `host`.

An attacker could for example exploit the command injection issue via XSS, even if you would have CSRF protection.

**Security: Command Injection**

You are vulnerable to command injection via `service` as well as `host`, meaning anyone using your script can execute arbitrary commands.

Even if only people who should be allowed to execute arbitrary commands ever have access to this script - a big if - it should be secure against this, as it may be exploited in combination with other issues, eg XSS or CSRF.

**Security: CSRF**

Your code doesn't have CSRF protection. If you don't have that in some other file that you didn't post, you should add it. Without CSRF protection, an attacker can get you to submit a request they define if you visit an attacker-controlled website while authenticated at your site.

**Security: GET fallback**

GET and POST shouldn't be treated interchangeably. Accepting POST data via GET makes exploitation of some issues such as CSRF easier.

**Duplication**

You duplicate this piece of code quite a lot:

```
$alert = "";
if(isset($_POST['alert'])){
    $alert = $_POST['alert'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['alert'])){
    $alert = $_GET['alert'];
}
```

If you extract the code to a function, you could get rid of quite a couple of lines, and avoid possible bugs that may happen because of copy-pasting.

(But as I said above, you shouldn't actually do this at all.)

**$isset**

I would get rid of this variable. Just check at the beginning if either value you need is set, and if not, return.

**Naming**

Don't abbreviate variable names, it makes code harder to read. Without proper context, I have no idea what `comm` or `curr` are.

**formatting**

You are not using enough spaces, eg after `,`.

**HTML**

Your HTML isn't valid, you can check this yourself, eg [here](https://validator.w3.org/check).

You are also using elements such as `&nbsp` to style your document, which you shouldn't. The same is true of using `<br>` for styling (it should only be used if it has a semantic meaning).

Comment: Marked down key words. I will read more on the topics, implement your points and upload the revised code hopefully tomorrow after work. The thing I need some more clarification about is correct html styling  - what keywords do you suggest here?

Comment: @Poyke (sorry for the late reply) generally, styling should happen via CSS. HTML is a markup language, which means that it describes syntax, not style. If this is more of a throw-away / very small internal project, it's probably fine to use HTML tags instead (I do too if it's not important and if I'm lazy), but it's really not the recommended approach.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$host = "";
if(isset($_POST['host'])){ #higher priority for post
    $host = $_POST['host'];
    $isset++;
}elseif(isset($_GET['host'])){ #check get only if post wasn't set
    $host = $_GET['host'];
    $isset++;
}
```

you might want to try something along the lines of

```
$host = (isset($_POST['host']) ? $_POST['host'] : '');
$host = (empty($host)          ? (isset($_GET['host']) ? $_GET['host'] : '')  : $host);
```

Do the same for the other parameters then, to check that you have at least one of the required parameters, use:

```
$isset = !empty($host) OR !empty($service);
```

Which lets you test to see if you have at least one of them using:

```
if ($isset)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however seems like line1 sets $host to be '' when there is no POST and after that $host is set. So line2 will never check the GET. tested and seems this is the case.

Comment: Corrected my answer. Used empty instead of !isset which is what it should have been. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Some minor tweaks:

`str_replace` accepts arrays, so you can write:

```
$searches = ["critical", "CRITICAL", "warning", "WARNING", "NOT OK", "OK"];
$replaces = [
"<b><font color=\"red\">critical</font></b>",
"<b><font color=\"red\">CRITICAL</font></b>",
"<b><font color=\"orange\">warning</font></b>",
"<b><font color=\"orange\">WARNING</font></b>"
"<b><font color=\"red\">NOT 0K</font></b>",
"<b><font color=\"green\">OK</font></b>",
];
$output = str_replace($searches, $replaces, $output);
```

Or better, use a regex like this:

```
$levels = [
"critical" => "red",
"warning" => "orange",
"NOT OK" => "red",
"OK" => "green",
];
$regex = "/".implode('|', array_keys($levels))."/i";
$output = preg_replace_callback($regex, function ($matches) {
    return "<b><font color=\"{$levels[$matches[0]]}\">{$matches[0]}</font></b>";
},$output);
```

Note the `i` modifier for regex, that makes searching case insensitive.

Also, your regex can be simplified:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback("/(\d{10})/",function ($matches) {  # switch epoch time to date time
    return date("Y-m-d | H:i:s",$matches[0]);
},$output);
```